# What's wrong with my regex to replace src and add class using preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm a bit lost here. I'm trying to replace `src` tag with `data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAPABAAAAAP///yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==` for lazy loading and add class `lazyload` so lazysizes could work. But none of that is successful here.

Am I missing something?

```
public static function filter_lazy_load_gravatar( $html ) {
    $html = preg_replace( '/src="(http:\/\/([^\/]+)\/)?([^"]+)"/', 'src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAPABAAAAAP///yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="', $html);

    $html = str_replace( 'srcset=', 'data-srcset=', $html );
    $pat = '/class="([^"]*)"/';
    $html = preg_replace($pat, 'class="$1 lazyload"', $html);
    return $html;
}
```

Input

```
<img alt="" src="http://gravatar.com/image.jpg" srcset="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/0b11f7eec98d2ee78414a4322ea94a01?s=400&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g 2x" class="avatar avatar-200 photo" height="200" width="200">
```

Expected output

```
<img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAPABAAAAAP///yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" data-srcset="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/0b11f7eec98d2ee78414a4322ea94a01?s=400&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g 2x" class="avatar avatar-200 photo lazyload" height="200" width="200">
```

Comment: What is `$html`? You probably should use a parser for this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php....or which regex fails currently? You don't need second regex actually something like `str_replace('class=", class="lazyload`

Comment: Never use regex on html... use a parser...

Comment: I'm doing WordPress development. For some reason when I do it never works $doc = DOMDocument::loadHTML( $html );

Comment: Expected output is the exact output... https://eval.in/413329

Comment: [Class 'DOMDocument' not found](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-import-html-pages-requires-php-xml-if-you-get-error-domdocument-not-found?replies=1)?